# Is spinal marrow haram to consume?

Tags: halal-haram, islamic-basis, food, meat

I've heard some people claim that ***spinal marrow*** or ***spinal cord*** is haram to eat. Is this claim true and what is the basis for this?

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not haram. At all. The prohibition is against blood, and marrow is not blood. Some may have confused that issue.

Answer (score -3):

Everything is Halal until proven otherwise. Allah said, “It is He Who hath created for you all things that are on earth.” (Quran 2:29). In other words, spinal marrow or spinal cord is Halal.

Majority of the Muslim scholars hold of its permissibility. However, some from the Shia religion rely on a fabricated hadith, "The worst of my ummah are those who consume bone marrow" (Bihar al-Anwaar , 62/293).

All in all, there is no evidence of prohibition.

Comment: This might answer the question but clearly needs clarification I at least would add (5:1) and (5:3-5:4) and maybe more. As you statement could -theoretically- easily be refuted by a counterexample or an exception.

Comment: How would you refute it? I am actually curious now.

Comment: Take any verse starting with: "Allah made unlawfull for you"  it shows that not all things are halal. So you must explicitly show that your "thing" is halal, by excluding it being haram.

Comment: Also, this is the position of the four schools of thought.

Comment: This can't be concluded from your statement!

Comment: It is not my statements. I am simply telling you that this is the position of the Jamhoor which in this case includes the four schools. Are you saying that this is not correct?

Comment: I'm saying this is not an answer as we expect here, answers should be well elaborated (this is not), focused on answering the actual question and any claim to be supported by evidences (as said your claim could need some support) (see [answer]).

Comment: If the book of Allah is not enough for you, I will simply delete  my response

Comment: That is up to you I only trying to help you to improve it.